# Is sylvester's criterion can indicate a positive semi-defined matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

for example i want to know if the matrix:
$\begin{pmatrix}a&2&0\\ 2&a+1&0\\ 0&0&a\end{pmatrix}$ is positive semi-defined $∀ m_i\le 0$
is it possible to use sylvester's criterion and demand
$a\le 0$
$a^2+a\le 0$
$a^2\left(a+1\right)-4a\le 0$
and find $a=\frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{2},\:a=\frac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{2}$
or criterion works only to positive defined matrix?
(i know that if a matrix is positive defined is also positive semi-defined,i'm just trying to figure out the principle)

Comment: The word is "semidefinite" by the way, not "semidefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the matrix is block-diagonal. Thus, it sufficient to check whether each of the submatrices
$$
\pmatrix{a & 2\\ 2 & a + 1}, \quad a
$$
are positive semidefinite. More generally, the naive generalization of Sylvester's criterion is **not** sufficient to ensure that a matrix is positive semidefinite. For example, the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&-1}
$$
has non-negative leading principal minors but is not positive semidefinite.